# Autofill OTP to the textbox when i receive message in ionic or cordova application

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

How to autofill otp in the textbox when I receive SMS in the ionic or Cordova application?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin to read sms from device and after reading the sms identify the OTP and update the model field bineded.

https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-sms

1. Add plugin using `cordova add plugin https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-sms`
2. use `listSMS();` or `startWatch()` function to read the messages.
3. Identify the OTP part in sms
4. Update the model.

Comment: Thanks, I used the same plugin with startWatch() and onSMSArrive event listener to do the same.

Comment: @ManishSingh Thanks. If you don't mind please upvote and accept the answer.. so , that other's who have the same issue can get the idea.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not free. Do you have any suggestion that is free to use and work both on android and ios?

Comment: @YogeshMittal how did you resolve this issue ?